# How can I add C++ optimization flags to ROS

Tags: ros, opencv, optimization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running an opencv code on ROS  and I really need to turn on the -O3 optimization flag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213795/how-can-i-add-c++-optimization-flags-to-ros/) by [adnansousi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23197/adnansousi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Call `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` to turn on the default optimization flags for release builds. `-O3` should be in there, as far as I know.

Otherwise, you can add compile flags on a per node basis by specifying `set_target_properties(<TARGET> PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-O3")` in the `CMakeLists.txt`. However, I'm not sure how this is handled then in combination with a build type.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adnansousi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23197/adnansousi/) on 2015-07-15**:
thank you very much. I just typed in catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release and it worked fine thanks.